# Combining Shuffle with Web Audio Playback

Tags: javascript, audio, shuffle

I would like to shuffle an array of audio files so that the file that plays when a button is clicked is different each time (and is then followed by the remaining audio files in the array, so that one click might trigger [1,3,2] and the next might trigger [2,1,3]. This was relatively simple with HTML Audio, but with Web Audio I can't wrap my head around it. Advice would be appreciated.

Here's the shuffle function I was using with HTML Audio:

```
function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
// While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {
// Pick a remaining element...
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
currentIndex -= 1;

// And swap it with the current element.
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
}
```

And here's the code I've been using to play back the audio array in order [1,2,3] with Web Audio.

```
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
this.context = context;
this.urlList = urlList;
this.onload = callback;
this.bufferList = new Array();
this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

var loader = this;

request.onload = function() {
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
        request.response,
        function(buffer) {
            if (!buffer) {
                alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                return;
            }
            loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
            if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
                loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
        }    
    );
}

request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');        
}

request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
    this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function loadAndPlay() {
try {
    context = new AudioContext();
}
catch(e) {
    alert("Web Audio API is not supported in this browser");
}

bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
    "IRELAND/harp1.ogg",
    "IRELAND/harp2.ogg",
    "IRELAND/harp3.ogg",
    ],
    finishedLoading
);


bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
// Create three sources and buffers
var harp1 = context.createBufferSource();
var harp2 = context.createBufferSource();
var harp3 = context.createBufferSource();
harp1.buffer = bufferList[0];
harp2.buffer = bufferList[1];
harp3.buffer = bufferList[2];

harp1.connect(context.destination);
harp2.connect(context.destination);
harp3.connect(context.destination); 
  // Play them staggered
harp1.start(0);
harp1.onended = function() {
harp2.start();     
}
harp2.onended = function() {
harp3.start();  
}
}
```

So the question is, how do I combine the first shuffle function with the playback of the array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could push the BufferSources into an array, then shuffle it, and then play the BufferSources from index `0`:

```
var harps = [];
harps.push(harp1, harp2, harp3);
harps = shuffle(harps);

harps[0].start(0);
harps[0].onended = function() {
    harps[1].start();
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to make this into a repeating cycle? That is, as soon as the array has been deplete, the array is reshuffled and played through again and again (forever, or until triggered to stop)? There seems to be some complication with Web Audio to play the same file twice.

Comment: Yeah, each `AudioBufferSourceNode` can only be started once in its lifetime. After all the nodes in the array have been played, you would need to create new `AudioBufferSourceNode`s, to which you can assign the same `AudioBuffer`s from your `bufferList`.